# How to change Issuer name in certificate (i have used keytool)?

Tags: java

> Owner: CN=gateway, OU=gateway, O=gateway, C=ss
>
> Issuer: CN=gateway, OU=gateway, O=gateway, C=ss
>
> Serial number: 4c05ed66
>
> Valid from: Wed Jun 02 11:04:30 IST 2010 until: Fri Jun 03 11:04:30 IST 2011
>
> Certificate fingerprints:
>
> ```
>      MD5:  E3:27:75:8D:96:CB:C3:67:EF:F0:5D:E1:D6:85:CD:0C
>      SHA1: 2E:8B:67:0D:AC:25:E2:99:50:61:60:88:BA:1F:1C:10:8F:41:7C:27
>
>      Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
>      Version: 3
> ```
>
> Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
>
> Certificate was added to keystore

Using Keytool i am generating KeyPair and Certificate. Below is the content of my certificate now i want to change the only Issuer name suppose i am verifying it and i want to make myself as a issuer so i want to enter my info here...Owner should be same only Issuer i want to change ..plz tell me how to do it??

Comment: I want to change the value of CN and O, did you have any success?

Answer (score 9):

You can't, you have to create a new certificate.

The certificate contains a signature of the data it presents (including Owner, Issuer, Fingerpint, ...) and that's what makes up the certificate in the first place.

Put differently: A certificate is **designed specifically** so that this data can't be modified after its creation.

Comment: ok suppose i am giving this certificate to verify..how will you verifiy it?? what signature you will add there?? and how??

Comment: Check if it is signed by a CA that you trust.

Comment: Is it not possible only to change CN and O? Seems to me these are there only for extra information?

Answer (score 0):

Using BurpSuite, you can modify the certificates Issuer Name.
Step 1: Copy paste the certificate data from Begin Certificate to End certificate 
Step 2: Decode the certificate information 
Step 3: Use the ASN.1 format to get details on Certificate information 
Step 4: Modify the information and encode it back to B-64 format.

But anyways the loading to the library will fail .